# Programmatically setting notification settings for embedded signers

Tags: docusignapi

I know you can configure notification settings in the Admin settings -- but it looks to be account wide. I'd like to enable "Send completion emails to embedded signers" only for those envelopes we indicate (hopefully through the Signer object EmailNotification?)

Do you know if that's possible? Here's the setting from Admin > Signing Settings > 
Envelope Delivery i'm referring to: 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this setting is at an account level, and it cannot be configured at an envelope level.

Answer (score 1):

As Amit says, that setting cannot be configured at the envelope level.

If you would like a specific signer on a specific envelope to receive a completion notification, add them to the envelope again as a Carbon Copy recipient at the end of the routing order.

Comment: Thanks @Drew that's a great way around that.